# Phonegap + Sencha Touch 2 on Android causes battery drain

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2, urbanairship.com, battery

I'm working on an app built with Phonegap and Sencha Touch 2. It also uses Urban Airship plugin for push notifications.

My problem is that on some devices running Android 4.0.4 it uses a lot of battery and CPU (~40% for both).

I've already switched off GPS, removed all analytics (network requests) from UA plugin and do pause all requests app makes when inactive (in background).

Do you know how can I profile it to find a leak or maybe there's some ready-to-use solutions for battery issues.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find out anything?

Comment: Roland, no, it was gone in one of the next builds, but I have no idea why

Comment: Interesting. I have a similar problem. Guess I'll have remove all plugins and reduce the app complexity. Then check for battery drain and add one at a time back. Thanks for the fast answer!